# kivymd window automatically opens in fullscreen and cursor not visible

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, frontend, kivymd

Recently I started studying KivyMD. Whenever I run a simple program the window opens in fullscreen mode(in which the bottom taskbar is not even visible, ie the entire laptop screen is covered by the KivyMD screen)
I thought this fullscreen issue was indeed part of KivyMD. I omitted that and started watching KivyMD tutorials on youtube. To my dismay all the tutorials I watched had the KivyMD screen opened in a non-fullscreen mode. This is the first problem I faced. The second issue is the invisible cursor. After I run the program the window opens in fullscreen mode and the cursor remains invisible. Whatever way I wipe on the trackpad, the cursor remains invisible. The moment I exit the program the cursor becomes visible. can someone rectify this issue...

Comment: Perhaps there are some bad setting in the `config.ini` file in the `.kivy` folder. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html).

Comment: Oh, Thank You so much. For me inside the config.ini, the cursor was set to the value 0. I changed that value to 1 and now the cursor is visible. And even got the window size rectified too. Thank You so much.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Following lines of code to top of your python file

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'visible')
Config.set('graphics', 'show_cursor', 1)
```

Kivy has a configuration file which determines the default settings. For Reference check following

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html